# JPA CascaseType - Persist and Merge Only

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have a @OneToMany from Parent to Children. It's bi-directional.

I want the only the cascade type to be persist and merge. Not remove. The only attribute value for cascade type is ALL or one of each of the other types on the enum.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use annotation  like this

```
@OneToMany (cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
```